# how to perform query in Postresql that returns a data count created grouped by month?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgresql, how do I perform a query that returns the sum amounts of rows created of a particular table by month? I would like the result to be something like:

```
month: January
count: 67

month: February
count: 85
....
....
```

Let's suppose a I have a table, `users`. This table has a primary key, `id`, and a `created_at` column with time stored in ISO8601 formatting. Last year `n` number of users were created, and now I want to know how many were created by month, and I want the data returned to me in the above format -- grouped by month and an associated count reflecting how many users were created that month.

Does anyone know how to perform the above SQL query in postgresql?

Comment: use `group by` .. this is simple. try it and post a question if you get stuck.

Comment: still struggling with this one... here's a sql query I've been trying but it's not working:

`select date_trunc('month', TIMESTAMP '2017-03-20 13:38:46.688-04') as "Month", count(*) from users where subscribed = true and '2017-03-20 13:38:46.688-04' > now() - interval '12 months' group by created_at;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query would look something like this:

```
select date_trunc('month', created_at) as mm, count(*)
from users u
where subscribed = true and
      created_at >= '2016-01-01' and
      created_at < '2017-01-01'
group by date_trunc('month', created_at);
```

I don't know where the constant `'2017-03-20 13:38:46.688-04'` is coming from.

Of course you can make the year comparison dynamic:

```
select date_trunc('month', created_at) as mm, count(*)
from users u
where subscribed = true and
      created_at >= date_trunc('year', now()) - interval '1 year' and
      created_at < date_trunc('year', now())
group by date_trunc('month', created_at);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What if I wanted the result to output the actual name of the month? So instead of, `2017-03-01 00:00:00-05`, the result would print out, `March`.

Comment: You would use `to_char(created_at, 'Month')`.